# 'Hide' items from a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

'Hide' an item from the RecyclerView. Remove an item but allow the user to bring it back. The user must be able to bring all the removed items back. Open to a different approach to this.

[image]

The link above is a screenshot of the list. I want to be able to hide an item from the list (as seen in the image above), but still allow the user to bring all hidden items back onto the list.

Code for populating the list.

```
    //Method used to retrieve all installed applications
    private ArrayList<AppData> getInstalledPackages() {
        List<String> appsList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<AppData> appDataArrayList = new ArrayList<AppData>();
        AppInfoExtractor apkInfoExtractor = new AppInfoExtractor(this);
        appsList = apkInfoExtractor.GetAllInstalledApkInfo();
        if (appsList != null && appsList.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < appsList.size(); i++) {

                AppData appData = new AppData();
                appData.setAppName(apkInfoExtractor.GetAppName(appsList.get(i)));
                appData.setPackageName(appsList.get(i));
                Version version = new Version();
                version.setVersionName(apkInfoExtractor.getVersionName(appsList.get(i)));
                version.setVersionCode(apkInfoExtractor.getAppVersionCode(appsList.get(i)));
                List<String> grantedPermissions = getPermissionsForPackage(appsList.get(i));
                List<String> grantedPermissionsShort = getShortPermissionStrings(grantedPermissions);
                version.setPermissions(grantedPermissionsShort);
                ArrayList<Version> versions = new ArrayList<Version>();
                versions.add(version);
                appData.setVersions(versions);
                appDataArrayList.add(appData);
            }
        }
        return appDataArrayList;
    }
```

Code for the List adapter.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

        AppInfoExtractor apkInfoExtractor = new AppInfoExtractor(context1);

        final String ApplicationPackageName = (String) stringList.get(position);
        final String ApplicationLabelName = apkInfoExtractor.GetAppName(ApplicationPackageName);
        Drawable drawable = apkInfoExtractor.getAppIconByPackageName(ApplicationPackageName);

        viewHolder.textView_App_Name.setText(ApplicationLabelName);

        viewHolder.textView_App_Package_Name.setText(ApplicationPackageName);
        viewHolder.tv_version_name.setText("Version Name: " + apkInfoExtractor.getVersionName(ApplicationPackageName));
        viewHolder.tv_version_code.setText("Version Code: " + apkInfoExtractor.getAppVersionCode(ApplicationPackageName));

        viewHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        //Adding click listener on CardView to open clicked application directly from here .
        viewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent perm = new Intent(context1, AppDetailActivity.class);
                perm.putExtra("PACKAGE_NAME", ApplicationPackageName);
                perm.putExtra("APP_NAME", ApplicationLabelName);
                context1.startActivity(perm);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: " I want to be able to hide an item from the list, but still allow the user to bring all hidden items back onto the list." Can you explain what you mean by hide and then bring it back?

Comment: @Abhi Pretend a user does not want an app on the list. I want to give them the option to hide an app they don't want to see. And if they change their mind, I want them to be able to un-hide the apps. Does that make more sense?

Comment: By "hide" you mean to remove from the list? After removing, from where can they see the removed items to unhide them?

Comment: @Abhi Yes! That's exactly it! I was hoping to include a button that would simply un-hide all of the hidden applications.

Comment: To be clear, you don't want to selectively unhide?

Comment: @Abhi I thought of that but I'm not sure how to go about with it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [Recyclerview Swipe to remove](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/09/android-recyclerview-swipe-delete-undo-using-itemtouchhelper/) to remove items from `recyclerView`.

To unhide all items add a menu option with the "Unhide All" option.
Store all deleted data while swiping in a list and append it to the `recyclerView` data when the menu option to "unhide all" is selected.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ItemTouchHelper to perform 'swipe-to-delete' functionality for the item in the RecyclerView. Once the item is deleted, show a Snackbar with 'Undo' action. On click of Undo, add the item back in the list again.
Please check [here](https://medium.com/@zackcosborn/step-by-step-recyclerview-swipe-to-delete-and-undo-7bbae1fce27e) and let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create another list to hold the hidden items, so when the user hides an item from the main list it gets removed from the main list and added to the hidden items list. And make a button unhide to bring them back to the main list and remove them from the hidden list.